# Trigger lambda based in calendar Dynamo table

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, serverless, amazon-sns

I'm developing a calendar system and I need to create a lambda function that is called from the DynamoDB Table. I have a table with a date column and I need this lambda function to be called every time an event starts.

This lambda will be responsible for registering a message in the SNS notified about the beginning of the event.

Tried using CloudWatch, cron, but nothing effective

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "every time an event starts", I assume every time there is an entry in the DynamoDB Table that has a date column.

You can create Lambda triggers with your DyanmoDB Table as source. There is this tutorial that you can follow - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html